# How to set prop in react bootstrap(Dropdown) from parent

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-props

I am customizing the Dropdown from the react-bootstrap react to create the component, but I have trouble retrieving the props.
This is my code in `index.js`, `src/components/Dropdown/index`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../Dropdown/index.css'

const DropdownItem = (name) => {
  return(
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle className="dropdown-button">
        Selection
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu className="dropdown-menu">
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">{name}</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">{name}</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
  );
}

export default DropdownItem;
```

The name I will render from `app.js`(`src/app`) is passed into the dropdown item like this

```
< DropdownItem name="Milk Tea"/>
```

But If I have a lot of items, how can I print them all in one dropdown group?
[image]

I can not do like this

```
< DropdownItem name="Milk Tea"/> 
< DropdownItem name="Fruit"/>
```

It's will render many dropdowns not drop item

Your help is very useful

Comment: it should be `const DropdownItem = (props)` and use like `props.name`

Comment: It still doesn't show for me the name of the item, although I already change like that

Comment: you should be using like this `< DropdownItem name="Milk Tea"/> < DropdownItem name="Fruit"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your help but, it makes double dropdown, how can I set many name item for 1 drop down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the child component logic wrong.
Your Child component is the whole Dropdown component as per I can see your code.
Therefore, you will have to pass down array of names as props.

Example.

```
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import "../Dropdown/index.css";

const DropdownItems = ({ nameList }) => {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle className="dropdown-button">Selection</Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu className="dropdown-menu">
        {nameList.map((name, index) => (
          <Dropdown.Item href={`#/action-${index}`}>{name}</Dropdown.Item>
        ))}
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};
```

In App.js

```
<DropdownItems nameList={["Milk Tea","Fruit"]} />
```

Comment: thank you so much, I understood for this my problem. Thank you again

Comment: @Kite my pleasure, happy to help a fellow dev anytime :)

Comment: @Kite, please accept my answer if i have satisfied your problem